# RapidJson kArrayType with String

Tags: c++, stdstring, rapidjson

I have following code but its cannot compiled.
I cannot think about a reason, please hlep.

```
rapidjson::Document jsonDoc;
jsonDoc.SetObject();
rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = jsonDoc.GetAllocator();

rapidjson::Value messageArr(rapidjson::kArrayType);

std::string test = std::string("TEST");
messageArr.PushBack(test.c_str(), allocator);
```

Giving me following error;

> error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘rapidjson::GenericValue >::PushBack(const char*,
>   rapidjson::GenericDocument >::AllocatorType&)’
>   messageArr.PushBack(test.c_str(), allocator);

Comment: Done - RapidJosn has different sorts of String Values: allocated (will need a length when constructing), simple `const char*` wrappers (which will blow if going out of scope) and/or `short strings` *15 chars or less - or somethng like that). Since you wanted with allocators, I assumed you wanted a by-copy StrValue - the answer shows how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Edited] - Solution:

```
  std::string test = std::string("TEST");
  rapidjson::Value strVal;
  strVal.SetString(test.c_str(), test.length(), allocator);
  messageArr.PushBack(strVal, allocator);
```

See [RapidJson tutorial - Create String](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#CreateString)

Fluent-style:

```
 messageArr.PushBack(
      rapidjson::Value{}.SetString(test.c_str(), test.length(), allocator),
      allocator
  );
```

Comment: I tried, but no luck, then giving the following error,      equired from here
/usr/include/rapidjson/document.h:1342:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >::GenericValue(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’
         GenericValue v(value);
                             ^

Comment: Did you ever get this to compile?  I get the same error when I try to pushback my rapidjson::Value & like he has on the rapidjson tutorial when they talk about copyFrom.

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace rapidjson;
using namespace std;

Value array(kArrayType);
string test = "TEST";
Value cat(test.c_str(), allocator);
array.PushBack(cat, allocator);
```